# Single Logout using com.coveo.SamlClient dependancy

Tags: java, single-sign-on

Hello Everyone I am new to SSO I have implememted SSO using  com.coveo.saml.SamlClient
I have implemeted SSO but now i have no idea on SingleLogout any suggestion will be appreciated?
I am using ADFS as a IDP?